# Pass HTTP Header 'Origin' to cgi with Apache server

Tags: apache, http-headers, cgi

I would like to examine the value of the HTTP 'Origin' field in a Python CGI script.
From looking at what Fiddler sniffs as being sent, and what cgi.test() shows as being visible, it seems that the Apache server is not passing this header field on.

How can I configure Apache to pass the HTTP 'Origin' Request Header to the cgi environment?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Phil.